# C++: Talk to and receive data from MySQL Server

Tags: c++, mysql, ssh, popen

Either this this question isn't asked often (possible), everyone knows how to do it (doubtful), or I don't know how to search for it (likely).

I want to get my C++ program talking to my MySQL server and able to run commands on it. I know MySQL has connector code available, but 1) it seems like much more than I need and 2) I just cannot seem to get it to work anyway.

I want to be able to test the program on my computer, so remote access would be necessary. I do have SSH for the server.

My final deployment will be able to run on the server itself.

Executing and receiving/parsing output from MySQL databases is quite easy to do by hand. I can't however, figure out which way to go to get my program to do this.

I figure I should be able to:
1. ssh into the web server (with password)
2. access the MySQL database
3. execute statements and retrieve their output

I've read a lot about fork() and popen(), but due to their read-only or write-only limitations (unless I misunderstand), I just don't know where to go. Obviously I'd just take out the SSH step when the time comes to deploy it on the server. Can somebody give me some direction on this, or is this just not possible (doubtful).

It is our own dedicated server so we have full reign with ssh and WHM, but I'd rather minimize the "intrusion" since I don't know enough about all the software on there if I broke something. I just want to communicate [directly] with the MySQL database.

Thanks so much! You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SSH access, then you're *way* overcomplicating this.

Step 1: Set up an SSH tunnel:

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 user@your.host.com
```

Step 2: Use the local port like normal (i.e. just refer to localhost)

```
mysql -u root -p < somescript.sql
```

However since you're using C++, you really should use a proper library (e.g. [MySQL++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/)). Educate yourself on [SSH tunnels](http://www.codemastershawn.com/library/tutorial/ssh.tunnel.php), they make life so much easier once you know about them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. And thanks for the link to MySQL++, let me spend some time on that. I'm teaching myself all of this stuff, so my knowledge can be all over the place sometimes. I appreciate your help!